# What happened to php-5.4.11 from Ondrej PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, php, apt-cache

I am in 12.04 so I added Ondrej's PPA to get PHP 5.4. So far so good but php-5.4.12 seems to be broken with our code and after a while of struggling I decided to downgrade to php-5.4.11 but `apt-cache showpkg php5` says:

```
Provides: 
5.4.12-1~precise+1 - 
5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 - 
5.3.10-1ubuntu3 -
```

apparently `5.4.11` is no longer kept in my system for some reason as I'm sure at some point in time I updated to `5.4.11` and then after a while to `5.4.12`.

The other strange thing is what happened to the `5.4.11` in the Odrenj PPA ?! Sure he doesn't just delete a package when a new one arrives (?)

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the PPA owner, Odrenj, and ask. How should anyone here know what that person does?

Comment: @mikewhatever You are absolutely right, but I thought perhaps this is some kind of routine or something since older versions of many packages seem to be missing (like `phpmyadmin` for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPA indeed does delete older packages when new version is uploaded.

For further reading about this, see:

- [Packaging/PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) ("Packages...in your PPA...until...superseded by another package")
- [Bug 215661](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/215661) ("it would be nice if launchpad allowed multiple versions of a package to be present in PPA" and the bug is [triaged](https://help.launchpad.net/Bugs/Statuses))

Comment: @maggotbrain How does this not answer the question? Too-short answers aren't automatically comments, [even if you think they're inadequate](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).

Comment: @maggotbrain The question is asking why the old package is gone. The answer is that PPA's don't keep old versions of a package when a newer version of the same package is added. This answer explains that, meeting all the requirements of an answer (and [none to be a good comment](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment)).

Comment: @maggotbrain as the OP it indeed sounds like my answer although I'm very surprised and some links to some documentation or official procedures that state the deletion would be even more nice.

Comment: Would you please give a reference or something ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit I've edited some references in. While I think this is your answer, you may want to wait a bit to accept it--someone may post a workaround explaining how to get that version of the package (other than from a PPA).

Comment: unfortunately it all sounds true :(

Comment: Well, I probably have the correct source files (*.dsc) somewhere (or can generate them easily from git), so if you have a place to build them I can send them to you.  That means extracting the sources (dpkg-source -x php5*dsc), installing build dependencies (apt-get build-dep php5) and building (dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us).

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for adding the references...  I didn't even know there's already a wishlist for such feature (and I doubt it would have any other use than eating the disk space).

Comment: @maggotbrain The user has asked me by email (probably following the advice of mikewhatever), so I _did_ answer his question here, so like it or not.  Good and accurate answer doesn't have to have several paragraphs of text.

Comment: @oerdnj Hey, I'm perfectly fine with that. I didn't make the connection to you being the PPA author until *after* I looked at it in the queue. At the time, it seemed like an off-the-cuff remark, to me. In any case, is the link I provided in my answer to the files the OP was asking about and could use? If not, I'll delete my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @maggotbrain Looks like it still works now, so you might keep it.  However there's no guarantee that those files will be kept there (and for how long).  For example see: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5/+build/4021038

Comment: @oerdnj - Buddy, I got 404 error on your `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/systemd/ubuntu precise main` and `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/systemd/ubuntu precise main`, so I put # on each line on `:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo nano ondrej-systemd-precise.list`,will this affect updating PHP using your PPA?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can download the php-5.4.11 .deb files for 12.04(precise)from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5/+build/4244330).

This archive also has the PPA author's name, Ondrej, at the top of the page. Each of the files just need to be manually downloaded and installed.